Base is set in vite.config.js but is the wrong value in import.meta.env.BASE_URL
I want to have the ability to set the base URL at build time. This is more for API calls than anything else - I don't want them going to https://localhost:7251 on production, but I also don't want to resort to anything convoluted to swap the URLs.
I've a vite.config.js file that looks like this:
export default defineConfig (({ command, mode, isSsrBuild, isPreview }) => {
    const commonConfig = {
      build: {
        outDir: '../../wwwroot/dist',
        assetsDir: '',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        manifest: true,
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            client: './src/client.js'
          }
        },
      },
      server: {
        port: 5173,
        strictPort: true,
        hmr: {
          clientPort: 5173
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        vue(),
        VueDevTools(),
      ],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
      }
    };

    let envConfig = {};
    if (command === 'serve') { // configure dev, serve is an alias of 'dev'
      envConfig = {
          base: 'https://localhost:7251/'
      };
    } else if (command === 'build') {
      envConfig = {
          // production URL
      };
    }

    return Object.assign(commonConfig, envConfig);
  }
)


According to the Vite docs, if I set the value of 'base' in vite.config.js, this will be available as import.meta.env.BASE_URL in the application. Yet everywhere I reference it in the application, the value is / and not https://localhost:7251.
I'm not sure what to try here. I found in the vue docs mention of a define property that supposedly nests env vars, but using it just gave me CORS errors on some new .mjs file.

Why not use different env variables per environment rather than doing it in the config file? You define them into a .env (no need to install anything for it) and use it in the given environment. With something like VITE_SOME_KEY=https://coolurl.com in production and your local localhost during dev? This is how most people manage this kind of workflow. Vite reference.

@kissu thanks, I'll go with this approach but will still be curious to hear what is going wrong with base -> BASE_URL, as I will likely need to set it to ensure static assets are resolved

Try to make a [repro] so that way you could isolate it and we could double-check what's wrong.
